# Failed linking file resource file

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I tried running the application on my phone (via USB) just to make sure it works and this error showed up.

When I looked in the error in more depth, it mentioned something about the centreHorizontal of the bottom of the XML file.

Tried some solutions they didn't work. any help would be great . thank you very much!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/include"/>
<include
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/hands"
    android:layout_centerHoriztonal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

```
package com.example.rockpaper;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b_rock, b_paper, b_scissors;
ImageView iv_cpu, iv_me;
String myChoice, cpuChoice, result;
Random r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv_cpu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_cpu);
    iv_me = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_me);

    b_rock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_rock);
    b_paper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_paper);
    b_scissors = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_scissors);

    r = new Random();

    b_rock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myChoice = "rock";
            iv_cpu.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock);
            calculate();

        }
    });
    b_paper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myChoice = "paper";
            iv_cpu.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);
            calculate();

        }
    });
    b_scissors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myChoice = "scissors";
            iv_cpu.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors);
            calculate();


        }
    });
}

public void calculate() {
    int cpu = r.nextInt(3);
    if (cpu == 0) {
        cpuChoice = "rock";
        iv_cpu.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock);
    } else if (cpu == 1) {
        cpuChoice = "paper";
        iv_cpu.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);

    } else if (cpu == 2) {
        cpuChoice = "scissors";
        iv_cpu.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors);
    }

    if(myChoice.equals("rock") && cpuChoice.equals("paper")){
        result = "you lose";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("rock") && cpuChoice.equals("scissors")){
        result = "you win";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("rock") && cpuChoice.equals("rock")){
        result = "draw";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("paper") && cpuChoice.equals("paper")){
        result = "draw";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("paper") && cpuChoice.equals("scissors")){
        result = "you lose";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("paper") && cpuChoice.equals("rock")){
        result = "you win";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("scissors") && cpuChoice.equals("paper")){
        result = "you win";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("scissors") && cpuChoice.equals("scissors")){
        result = "draw";
    } else
    if(myChoice.equals("scissors") && cpuChoice.equals("rock")){
        result = "you lose";
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
 }
```

The error message in more detail

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root layout is `ConstraintLayout` but these

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

attributes belong to `RelativeLayout`

**Solution**

Either change your root layout to  `RelativeLayout` or give the corresponding positioning elements of `ConstraintLayout` inside `include` tag

Like

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf = "id or parent" 
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf = "id or parent" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "id or parent" 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "id or parent"
```

Comment: What do you mean by  giving the corresponding positions of ConstraintLayout inside include tag